# Will using NIO decoder cause entire file to be read?

Tags: java, memory-management, file-io, nio

I am considering using Java NIO to process files and using the decoder capability to handle different charsets. My concern is that this could lead to efficiency or memory problems if the decoder attempts to read the entire file at the outset. For example, given the following code (exception handlers omitted for clarity):

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName( "ISO-8859-15" );
CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( file );
FileChannel fc = fis.getChannel();
int lenFile = (int)fc.size();
MappedByteBuffer bufferFile = fc.map( FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, lenFile );
CharBuffer cb = decoder.decode( bufferFile ); // <--- possible problem here
// process character buffer
fc.close();
```

In the line where the CharBuffer is created my concern is that the decoder would create a buffer to contain the entire file, which could be gigabytes in size and thus cause a memory problem. Does it try to create a buffer the size of the file? Is there a way to control how large the buffer is?

Comment: You've mapped the entire file and decoded the entire mapped buffer, so of course you will get another buffer the size of the file. But if the file is gigabytes you shouldn't be mapping it in the first place.

Comment: So, what is the right way to decode a potentially large file without having to worry about memory problems?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really read the file but it maps it into memory. This means that the parts of the file are read on demand and then discarded if operating system realizes it hasn't been accessed for some time.

However it allocates huge CharBuffer for the output as this is basically processing result.

Here I would consider implementing simple while loop - read the bytes, call decode, flush current output and repeat until reaching end of file.

Comment: That would seem to make sense. If I read characters into a buffer before decoding them, however, how do I prevent the buffer end from accidentally splitting a multi-byte character? Also, won't there be an issue in that a Unicode or UTF-8 string needs to have some kind of preamble that will be in the first buffer read, but none of the subsequent ones?

Comment: `CharsetDecoder`s maintain their states when it comes to reading partial input. Check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html#decode(java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20java.nio.CharBuffer,%20boolean)), specifically `endOfInput` parameter.